# SQL Select last message for each contact who user has been mailing with

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a messaging system that reminds of a emailing system - the messages are stored as duplicates - one for the sender and one for the reciver. The "messages" table structure is:

```
message_id  |  date_and_time  |  text  |  user_id  |  contact_id  |  sender_id
```

Only thing I have here is the `user_id` and I need to select the last message for all the contacts and order the whole result by the `date_and_time DESC` so I get result similar to this (`user_id=40`):

```
message_id  |  date_and_time       |  text  |  user_id  |  contact_id  |  sender_id
1           |  2014-01-02 20:00:00 | Test 1 |  40       |  32          |  40
4           |  2014-01-02 12:00:00 | Test 2 |  40       |  99          |  99
6           |  2014-01-02 09:00:00 | Test 3 |  40       |  28          |  40
```

I was looking to other answers and tried to do the query for me but I didnt succeed.

My guess is that it is something with the `MAX()` and `GROUP BY`+`ORDER BY`
but

```
SELECT contact_id, MAX(date_and_time) as time_when, * 
FROM messages WHERE user_id = 40
GROUP BY contact_id, time_when
ORDER BY date_and_time DESC
```

throws an error...

Where is the error in my query or how should my query look like?

Thanks.
**EDIT:** I am using  MySQL(5.6.14)

## EDIT2

Problem solved thanks to @AgRizzo answer :)

Comment: what is the error you are receiving?

Comment: The problem is you are trying to GROUP BY your aggregate function (i.e., time_when). You need to look for solutions that solve _TOP N PER GROUP_ to solve your problem

Comment: @amaster507 `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM messages WHERE user_id = 40 GROUP BY contact_id, time_when ORDER BY date' at line 1`

Comment: @AgRizzo *TOP N PER GROUP*? could you please explain more on that or give a link?

Comment: I believe that you need to specify your columns instead of using `*`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the last message for all the contacts, use this:

```
SELECT messages.*
FROM messages
JOIN (SELECT contact_id, MAX(date_and_time) as time_when
      FROM messages
      GROUP BY contact_id) AS mostrecent
  ON mostrecent.contact_id = messages.contact_id
    AND mostrecent.time_when = messages.date_and_time
ORDER BY date_and_time DESC
```

Comment: @jave.web - it should be ok now (typo - I changed it above from `JOIN` to `FROM`)

Comment: Oh I found the "mistake" I just had to change `FROM messages` to `FROM messages
WHERE user_id = 40` (40=>custom user_id) , :) please edit ! thanks :) (now it works)

Answer (score 1):

May you try LEFT JOIN ?

```
SELECT a.*
FROM messages a LEFT JOIN messages b ON a.user_id = b.user_id AND a.date_and_time < b.date_and_time
WHERE b.user_id IS NULL
```

Comment: How does this apply the given `user_id` ?

Comment: We need **any field** from table b, because we need only rows with b.* are null.

Answer (score 0):

`*` should be used before all custom aliases and then specify your remaining columns/custom aliases,try below

```
SELECT *,contact_id, MAX(date_and_time) as time_when 
FROM messages WHERE user_id = 40
GROUP BY contact_id, date_and_time
ORDER BY date_and_time DESC
```

Comment: This seems to have same effect as `SELECT * FROM messages WHERE user_id=56 ORDER BY date_and_time DESC` - doesnt help much :/